# How to support disconnections or reboots for Jenkins slaves on Windows?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I have many long running jobs that take almost a day to complete. Splitting is not possible. If the network fails then all progress is lost.
How can a slave survive disconnections?

**EDIT 1**

I have around 300 slaves running in Windows tied to one single Jenkins instance.

Slaves are connected using the manual method `java - jar slave.jar -jlnpUrl <serverUrl> <slaveName>`.  I cannot run them as a regular Windows service because some tests manipulate GUI elements and require a real interactive session otherwise test fail.

**EDIT 2**

According to [Jenkins Cookbook](http://jenkins-cookbook.cloudbees.com/docs/jenkins-cookbook/_distributed_builds_architecture.html#_master_slave_communication_protocols) I should be using Cygwin + OpenSSH approach instead of custom script with JLNP-connector. Could this improve stability?

Comment: Your slaves are running or Windows or Linux? If it's Linux, are you managing your slaves with SSH (from the master)? With SSH, I think the master will immediately try to reconnect if the network fails.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins was not originally designed for builds to survive across server or slave restarts. There is a **CloudBees Long-Running Build plugin** that [supports long-running builds](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2014/03/support-for-long-running-builds-in.html) but, unfortunately, it is available only for enterprise users and still beta.

I didn't find any free alternative and would suggest you to try to improve your network stability and to split your long running jobs. At least you can divide your tests on logical groups (test suites).

Comment: Are there any alternatives for regular users? How can I mimic the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins now has a workflow plugin. It claims to handle "server" restart and loss-of connectivity with slave.

[From the link](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/workflow-plugin-10)

> A key feature of a workflow execution is that it's suspendable. That
>   is, while the workflow is running your script, you can shut down
>   Jenkins or lose a connectivity to a slave. When it comes back, Jenkins
>   will still remember what it was doing, and your workflow script
>   resumes execution as if it was never interrupted. A technique known as
>   the "continuation-passing style" execution plays a key role in
>   achieving this.

(not tested at all)

Edit: Copied from @Jesse Glick's comments :

Workflow is open source and available for anyone running Jenkins 1.580.1+ or later. CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise does include a checkpoint feature, but this is not necessary simply to have a build survive slave disconnections and Jenkins restarts: that is automatic

Comment: I have experimented with **Workflow Plugin** but it is unstable. Ther is a *Checkpoint* feature that act as a save state where you can continue from, unfortunatelly this is only avaliable for enterprise users.

Comment: Contrary to @jayan, Workflow is open source and available for anyone running Jenkins 1.580.1+ or later. CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise does include a checkpoint feature, but this is not necessary simply to have a build survive slave disconnections and Jenkins restarts: that is automatic.